# lftp mirror : exclude zip files in parent directory, but not in subdirectories

Tags: mirror, lftp

I use lftp's mirror command to retrieve data from a FTP server.
I want to exclude zip files that are on the parent directory, but not those that are in subdirectories.

This command:
`lftp ftp://server_ip -e "mirror -a -e --exclude-glob '*.zip' / /where/to/put/the/data ; quit"`
Excludes all zip files, wherever they are located

This one:
`lftp ftp://server_ip -e "mirror -a -e --exclude-glob '/*.zip' / /where/to/put/the/data ; quit"`
Does not exclude any zip file anymore.

Can someone help ?